# How to append to a data frame from multiple loops

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a code, which takes in files from csv and takes a price difference, but to make it simplar I made a reproducible example as seen below. I want to append each result to the end of a specific column name. For example the first loop will go through size 1 and minute 1 so it should append to column names 1;1, for file2, file 3, file4. So the output should be :

```
1;1  1;2   1;3   2;1  2;2  2;3      
0    0     0       same below as for 1
0    0     0
2    2     2
2    2     2
4    4     4
4    4     4
5    5     5
0    0     0
0    0     0
0    0     0
2    2     2
2    2     2
4    4     4
4    4     4
6    6     6
6    6     6
0    0     0
0    0     0
0    0     0
2    2     2
2    2     2
4    4     4
4    4     4
6    6     6
7    7     7
```

I am using a loop to set prefixed data frame columns, because in my original code the number of minutes, sizes, and files is inputted by the user.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file =[1,2,3,4,5,6,6,2]
file2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
file3=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
file4=[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
size=[1,2]
minutes=[1,2,3]
list1=[file,file2,file3]
data=pd.DataFrame(file)
data2=pd.DataFrame(file2)
data3=pd.DataFrame(file3)
list1=(data,data2,data3)
datas=pd.DataFrame(file4)
col_names = [str(sizer)+';'+str(number) for sizer in size for number in minutes]
datanew=pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)


for sizes in size:
    for minute in minutes:
        for files in list1:
            pricediff=files-data
             datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]=datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)].append(pricediff,ignore_index=True)
print(datanew)
```

Edit: When trying this line: `datanew=datanew.append({str(sizes)+';'+str(minute): df['pricediff']},ignore_index=True)` It appends the data but the result isn't "clean"

The result from my original data, gives me this:

```
    111;5.0,1111;5.0
"0                                          4.5
1                                          0.5
2                                            8
3                                            8
4                                            8
                        ...                   
704                                        3.5
705                                        0.5
706                                       11.5
707                                        0.5
708                                        9.0
Name: pricediff, Length: 709, dtype: object",
"price    0.0
0        0.0
Name: pricediff, dtype: float64",
"0      6.5
1      6.5
2      3.5
3     13.0
Name: pricediff, Length: 4, dtype: float64",
```

Comment: You might want to look into using a MultiIndex, in order to simply those columns names.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are trying to append new columns or append new rows. `datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]=pricediff` will attempt to create a new column. I recommend printing out the different objects at each step of the process to compare what your code is producing to what you intended. This might help you find where the dimensions are going wrong.

Comment: I edited it I want to append the data to the end of that specific column.

Comment: remember, that you are crating an array, where all the rows / columns of that specific dimension need to have the same size. For a regular np array, I don't think that it is possible to have an array that looks like this `[[1,2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1]]`.

Comment: It's essentially a nxm matrix, bc I just want to create m columns, and append to them. The rows are not important because in my original code they vary.

Comment: I want to append to a data frame, with set columns.

Comment: What is the "right" way to write `datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]=datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)].append(pricediff)` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```py
datanew=datanew.append({str(sizes)+';'+str(minute): pricediff}, ignore_index=True)
```

This happens because you cannot change length of a single column of a dataframe without modifying length of the whole data frame.

Now consider the below as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"a": list("xyzpqr"), "b": [1,3,5,4,2,7], "c": list("pqrtuv")})

print(df)

#this will fail:
#df["c"]=df["c"].append("abc", ignore_index=True)
#print(df)

#what you can do instead:
df=df.append({"c": "abc"}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)

#you can even create new column that way:
df=df.append({"x": "abc"}, ignore_index=True)
```

**Edit**

In order to append `pd.Series` do literally the same:

```py
abc=pd.Series([-1,-2,-3], name="c")
df=df.append({"c": abc}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)

abc=pd.Series([-1,-2,-3], name="x")
df=df.append({"x": abc}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: What if I want to append a column from another dataframe. For example a column from another dataframe like df2['c'] into your column df['c'] example above. Because, in my question pricediff is from a different dataframe.

Comment: Try now - I added this option (do the same, just inside your dict marking which column you want to extend put ```pd.Series``` you wanna add there)

Comment: It isn't a series, it is just another column from a data frame. Like in my example: I do 'datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]=datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)].append(df['pricediff'],ignore_index=True)'  , price diff is a column from a different data frame, that I am trying to append to 'datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]`

Comment: In your example: 'df=df.append({"c": abc}, ignore_index=True)' how do you input it in a specific column in 'df'. My goal is to append df['pricediff']  to ''datanew[str(sizes)+';'+str(minute)]' as you see they are different dataframes, and I want to add to a specific column

Comment: Yup, so per my example, what I mean is: ```datanew=datanew.append({str(sizes)+';'+str(minute): df['pricediff']},ignore_index=True)```

Comment: Why does that not append properly? I see the dataframe column being added but it only gives the snipet, and says Name: pricediff, dty...   under the rows added to that column . When I did datanew[str(size)+';'+str(number)]=df['pricediff'] , it gave me clean data but didn't append to existing data frame, just got data of last columns added. Do I have to concat, maybe?

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused- I understood you want to append i.e. add to the existing dataframe, to given column to the bottom of it, is it right? What do you mean by "clean data" here? Could you share before+after what do you expect to be added where exactly (can be drawing for instance)?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. I added the result of what I mean above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207920/discussion-between-grzegorz-skibinski-and-aspiringcoder).